# tflearn: I am getting unexpected keyword argument for tflearn.models.dnn.DNN best_checkpoint_path

Tags: tflearn

Using tflearn, I am getting "unexpected keyword argument" for the argument best_checkpoint_path when setting tflearn.models.dnn.DNN.

checkpoint_path works ok but best_checkpoint_path doesn't...

Answer (score 0):

I answered your original question on github. At least it works for me.

tl,dr: You have to set a metric, set show_metric to True, and of course the best_checkpoint_path.

Hope it helps!

https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/pull/265